# jquery extend - array of objects

Tags: javascript, jquery

Say I have a Form object which has an array of Tab objects.

```
var Tab = function (options) {
    return ($jQuery.extend(true, {
        id: 'foo',
        title: 'Foo'
    }, options));
}

var Form = function (options) {
    return ($jQuery.extend(true, {
        id: 'foo',
        tabs: [new Tab()]
    }, options));
}
```

I can use this:

```
var myForm = new Form({tabs: [new Tab({id: 'bar'}), new Tab({title: 'Bar'}), new Tab({id: 'bar', title: 'Bar'})]});
```

To get:

```
myForm.tabs[0] => {id: 'bar', title: 'foo'}
myForm.tabs[1] => {id: 'foo', title: 'Bar'}
myForm.tabs[2] => {id: 'bar', title: 'Bar'}
```

But is it possible to somehow do this:

```
var myForm = new Form({tabs: [{id: 'bar'}, {title: 'Bar'}, {id: 'bar', title: 'Bar'}]});
```

And get the same result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can loop over the tabs and check whether they are a `Tab` object, e.g. (*untested*):

```
var Form = function (options) {
    if(options && options.tabs) {
        var tabs = options.tabs;
        for(var i = 0, l = tabs.length; i < l; ++i) {
            if(!(tabs[i] instanceof Tab)) {
                tabs[i] = new Tab(tabs[i]);
            }
        }
    }

    return ($jQuery.extend(true, {
        id: 'foo',
        tabs: [new Tab()]
    }, options));
}
```

Reference: [`instanceof`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Special_Operators/instanceof_Operator)

Comment: Thanks. I was hoping there would be a simple way of doing this without writing additional code to handle it. This will do the job. Thanks again!