# Modifying jQuery extend to push array items within objects but extend other objects

Tags: javascript, jquery, extend

I'm thinking this must be a common problem but can't seem to find the solution. 
Using JSON config files to extend a jQuery object that contains objects and arrays.

For the objects and simple properties, I want to overwrite (as `extend` does nicely).

For the arrays there may or may not be existing items.

Currently an array just overwrites the first elements

```
var sourceObj = {propterty:"change Me",anArray:[{name:"first"},{name:"second"}]},
    configJSON = '{"propterty":"New Val","anArray":[{"name":"third"}]}',
    configObj = JSON.parse(configJSON);

$.extend(true,sourceObj,configObj);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/PmuwV/

This returns:

```
{propterty:"New Val" , anArray:[{name:"third"},{name:"second"}}
```

Can I instead get:

```
{propterty:"New Val",anArray:[{name:"first"},{name:"second"},{name:"third"}]}
```

while ALSO allowing for updating "first" and "second" objects?

```
"anArray":[{"name":"second","newProp":"add newProp to second"}]
```

Could/should `extend` be modified to compare array items and extend or add based on some rule or set property value such as "name"?

Thanks for any advice or pointers.

Comment: This seems to be the the closest i've found that might do it - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3748697/jquery-extend-array-of-objects

Comment: The normal use of `$.extend` is for merging user-supplied options with defaults. In this case, it's usually best for a new property to completely replace the one in the original object; appending array properties doesn't fit in with the way it's typically used. What do you need this for?

Comment: @Barmar true that is one use case, but there are many others...including extending new functions/methods to jQuery object itself

Comment: From `$.extend` docs :`The merge performed by $.extend() is not recursive by default; if a property of the first object is itself an object or array, it will be completely overwritten by a property with the same key in the second object.` http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.extend/

Comment: @charlietfl Would those uses require appending array properties like this?

Comment: @charlietfl He knows that -- he's asking whether it would be reasonable to change that definition.

Comment: would need to loop over the object and map new array

Comment: Thanks to you both. I'm getting this config to extend the display of a form from another system. The JSON config format needs to be pretty simple and consistent as we are dealing with a large number of forms. Jquery.Extend does almost exactly what I want but just not with arrays (as documented). So could/should I "extend" Extend or essentially rebuild this functionality?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used this solution http://jsfiddle.net/PmuwV/2/ 
 modified from [How can I merge properties of two JavaScript objects dynamically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/171251/how-can-i-merge-properties-of-two-javascript-objects-dynamically) also from [JavaScript equivalent of jQuery's extend method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11197247/javascript-equivalent-of-jquerys-extend-method?rq=1)

requires isDOMNode()
I just added in a jquery merge (yes I feel dirty too) on arrays in which duplicates will need to be cleaned up post merge.
The Jquery source for extend does something very similar but i found this to be more readable.

```
function mergeRecursive() {
  // _mergeRecursive does the actual job with two arguments.
  var _mergeRecursive = function (dst, src) {
    if ( isDOMNode(src) || typeof src!=='object' || src===null) {
      return dst; 
    }

    for ( var p in src ) {

//my added bit here - [SB]
      if ($.isArray(src[p])){
          $.merge(dst[p],src[p]);
          var dupes = {},
               singles = [];
          $.each(  dst[p], function(i, el) {
             if ((dupes[el.name] > -1) &&  (el.name)) {
                 $.extend(singles[dupes[el.name]],el);
             }else{
                  if (el.name ){
                     dupes[el.name] = i;
                  }
                 singles.push(el);
             }
         });
         dst[p] = singles;
         }
         continue;        
      }
//the rest is original - [SB]

      if( !src.hasOwnProperty(p) ) continue;
      if ( src[p]===undefined ) continue;
      if ( typeof src[p]!=='object' || src[p]===null) {
        dst[p] = src[p];
      } else if ( typeof dst[p]!=='object' || dst[p]===null ) {
        dst[p] = _mergeRecursive(src[p].constructor===Array ? [] : {}, src[p]); 
      } else {              
        _mergeRecursive(dst[p], src[p]);
      }
    }
    return dst;
  }

  // Loop through arguments and merge them into the first argument. 
  var out = arguments[0];
  if ( typeof out!=='object' || out===null) return out;
  for ( var i=1, il=arguments.length; i<il; i++ ) {
    _mergeRecursive(out, arguments[i]);
  }
  return out;
}
```

Comment: updated at http://jsfiddle.net/PmuwV/5/ to merge duplicate array objects with a particular matching property

Comment: Needed something similar so I modified yours a bit to use underscore: http://codepen.io/clouddueling/pen/nFDCH

Comment: Nice solution but I found 2 bugs found in the above code, so I added an 'Answer' with the updated code.

Answer (score 2):

It's quite straightforward with [lodash library](https://lodash.com/docs#merge)

```
var targetObj = {
    customerId: "123", 
    orders: [
        "item1", "item2"
    ]
};

var otherObj = {
    customerName: "John", 
    orders: [
        "item3", "item4"
    ]
};

_.merge(targetObj, otherObj, function (a, b) {
  if (_.isArray(a)) {
    return a.concat(b);
  }
});
```

Result is:

```
targetObj = {
    customerId: "123",
    customerName: "John",
    orders: [
        "item1", "item2", "item3", "item4"
    ]       
}
```

Comment: For anyone reading this in 2016 or after, it seems that the correct lodash function for the example above today is `_.mergeWith()`

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old, but I found this post and used Steve Blacks code above but found a few bugs :

1. Theres an extra '}' before the 'continue' in the isArray section.
2. If the source did not have the array at all, it would throw an
   error, so I added this into the isArray section

   ```
   if ( !dst[p] ) {
       dst[p] = src[p];
       continue;
   }
   ```

So the finished code looks like this :

```
function isDOMNode(v) {
    if ( v===null ) return false;
    if ( typeof v!=='object' ) return false;
    if ( !('nodeName' in v) ) return false; 
    var nn = v.nodeName;
    try {
      v.nodeName = 'is readonly?';
    } catch (e) {
      return true;
    }
    if ( v.nodeName===nn ) return true;
    v.nodeName = nn;
    return false;
}

function mergeRecursive() {
    // _mergeRecursive does the actual job with two arguments.
    var _mergeRecursive = function (dst, src) {
        if ( isDOMNode(src) || typeof src!=='object' || src===null) {
            return dst; 
        }

        for ( var p in src ) {
            if ($.isArray(src[p])) {
                if ( !dst[p] ) {
                    dst[p] = src[p];
                    continue;
                }
                $.merge(dst[p],src[p]);
                var dupes = {}, singles = [];
                $.each( dst[p], function(i, el) {
                    if ((dupes[el.name] > -1) &&  (el.name)) {
                        $.extend(singles[dupes[el.name]],el);
                    } else {
                        if (el.name) {
                            dupes[el.name] = i;
                        }
                     singles.push(el);
                   }
                });
                dst[p] = singles;
                continue;        
            }

            if ( !src.hasOwnProperty(p) ) continue;
            if ( src[p]===undefined )     continue;
            if ( typeof src[p]!=='object' || src[p]===null) {
                dst[p] = src[p];
            } else if ( typeof dst[p]!=='object' || dst[p]===null ) {
                dst[p] = _mergeRecursive(src[p].constructor===Array ? [] : {}, src[p]); 
            } else {              
                _mergeRecursive(dst[p], src[p]);
            }
        }
        return dst;
    }

    // Loop through arguments and merge them into the first argument. 
    var out = arguments[0];
    if ( typeof out!=='object' || out===null) return out;
    for ( var i=1, il=arguments.length; i<il; i++ ) {
      _mergeRecursive(out, arguments[i]);
    }
    return out;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="./jquery-2.1.3.js"></script> <!-- for json extend / merge -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="./jQuery.extendext.min.js"></script> <!-- for json extend / merge - with array extend (instead of array overwrite) - https://github.com/mistic100/jQuery.extendext -->

<script>
var jsonResult = {};
var json1 =
{
    "properties":
    {
        "street_address": { "type": "string" },
        "city": { "type": "string" },
        "state": { "type": "string" }
    },
    "required": ["street_address", "city", "state"]
};
var json2 =
{
    "properties":
    {
        "country": { "type": "string" },
        "country-dial-code": { "type": "integer" },
        "country-short": { "type": "string" }
    },
    "required": ["country", "country-dial-code", "country-short"]
};
$.extendext(true, 'extend', jsonResult, json1, json2);
console.log(JSON.stringify(jsonResult));
/* output ->
{   "properties":
    {   "street_address":{"type":"string"},
        "city":{"type":"string"},
        "state":{"type":"string"},
        "country":{"type":"string"},
        "country-dial-code":{"type":"integer"},
        "country-short":{"type":"string"}
    },
    "required":["street_address","city","state","country","country-dial-code","country-short"]
}
*/
</script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: key "F12" to view console