# JQuery $.extend() recursivity peculiarity

Tags: javascript, jquery, extend

I want to extend an object in a specific position in an array, without having to send the whole array again.

Example:

You start out with the array like this:

```
sensors = [{value: 10}, {value: 20}];
```

Now say I want to change the value of the second sensor, I can do this in jQuery:

```
newSensorValue = {1: {value:30}};
$.extend(true, sensors, newSensorValue);
// sensors = [{value: 10}, {value: 30}];
```

However, if the array is not directly the object that is merged, this does not work:

```
node = {x: 10, y: 10, node_id: 1, sensors: [
    {sensor_id: 1, value: 10}, 
    {sensor_id: 2, value: 20}
]};
newNodeData = {sensors: {
    1: {value:30}
}};
$.extend(true, node, newNodeData);
// node = {x: 10, y: 10, node_id: 1, sensors: {
//     1: {value:30}
// }};
```

Why does $.extend() suddenly behave differently if the array is nested in an object?

My own solution would be to create an array of empty objects, only giving the object that I want to change the "value" attribute, like:

```
newNodeData = {sensors: [
    {}, {value: 30}
]};
```

Since this seems rather ugly, is there a better way to do this?
I would prefer to keep the sensors attribute an array, since I like to use forEach to go through each sensor quickly.

EDIT: forgot to mention that if I do

```
$.extend(true, node.sensors, newNodeData.sensors);
```

It works the same as in the first example (i.e. it works)

Comment: have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13280232/modifying-jquery-extend-to-push-array-items-within-objects-but-extend-other-obje

Comment: If I understand that version correctly, I should give some kind of extra property (like a sensor_id), on which the code would then decide to merge the array or not, am I correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could leave the element empty when you don't want to change it.

```
node = {x: 10, y: 10, node_id: 1, sensors: [
    {sensor_id: 1, value: 10}, 
    {sensor_id: 2, value: 20}
]};
newNodeData = {sensors: [,{value:30}]};
$.extend(true, node, newNodeData);
```

Comment: How much extra memory would that approach cost? Just in the interest of efficiency